# Gnuplot: plot 2D graph with variable points sizes and colors

Tags: plot, colors, gnuplot, javaplot

I have been trying to plot scatter data with points where the size and colors depend on the input. I have check some others examples and I get to write this, but then I get that error message

```
plot '-' using 1:2:3:4:5 with labels hypertext point pt 7 ps var lc rgb variable    
     Too many using specs for this style
```

What I am missing? I know plot with labels and point size works fine using 4 columns, namely 1:2:3:4, but as soon as I add the 5th input the error appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That simply tells you, that you cannot use variable points size and variable colors with the `labels` plotting style.

As workaround you can first draw the labels with the hypertext using white as point color, and then the colored points.

```
plot 'data.txt' using 1:2:3:4 with labels hypertext point pt 7 ps var lc rgb 'white',\
 '' using 1:2:4:5 with points pt 7 ps var lc rgb variable
```

Note, that with this solution you must send your data twice if you read from stdin.

Comment: Excelent, I was thinking this approach too and it works just great.

Comment: I had problem though, I am using a local defined palette so I use as input:

`plot '-' using 1:2:3:4 with labels hypertext point pt -1 ps var lc "white" title 'Datafile 1', '-' using 1:2:3:4 w point pt 7 ps var lc palette var title 'Datafile 2'`
and although it is plotted correctly i receive the error msg 
`unexpected or unrecognized token` pointing to palette and var. Since I am using javaplot it causing my graph to close

Comment: Because that's the wrong syntax, just use `lc palette`, without `var`.